# How to render div/component in other places in vue?

Tags: vue.js

How to render a div/component in other places on my component **without** make the duplicate content as separate component in vue? or separate the duplicate content from the targets?

for example this is the div I want to duplicate:

```
<div>blabla {{somecontent}}</div>
```

and I want to render in those places (all the code should be in one component):

```
<section>
 <div> __HERE__ </div>
</section>
<section>
 <div> __HERE__ </div>
</section>
```

I think want I expect is something like this:

```
<div #blabla>blabla {{somecontent}}</div>
<section>
 <div> {{blabla}} </div>
</section>
<section>
 <div> {{blabla}} </div>
</section>
```

Comment: There is a simple solution using `directive`, but I don't think that it would satisfy your needs. [You can find it here](https://jsfiddle.net/sryn4Lx1/)

Answer (score 0):

A good solution is creating a Vue component. I always try to create component. AS question demand I give a solution here.

You can create a computed or a method that will render the component like this

```
<script>
   ...,
   computed: {
       renderBlaBla() {
          return `<div #blabla>blabla ${this.somecontent}</div>`
       }
   },
   ....
</script>
```

and in the template section

```
<section>
     <div v-html="renderBlaBla"></div>
</section>
<section>
    <div v-html="renderBlaBla"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: @EstusFlask is it write now?

Comment: I'd suggest to add a note on v-html. It's a security threat and shouldn't be used with user-defined data.

Comment: @JonSud yes. this is not a good solution. I always try to create different component. and then include it. But As Question demand, I give a solution here.